# Not able to start redhat httpd service

Tags: linux, apache, unix, httpd.conf

When I try to start the httpd service it is failing with the error :

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

output of journalctl -xe

```
  The result is failed.
    Dec 08 04:09:49 uls-**** systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
    Dec 08 04:09:49 uls-******** systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
    Dec 08 04:09:49 uls-******** sudo[67525]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
    Dec 08 04:09:49 uls-******** polkitd[854]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:67526:3062933569 (system bus name :1.159161, object path /org/
    Dec 08 04:10:01 uls-******** systemd[1]: Started Session 78106 of user root.
    -- Subject: Unit session-78106.scope has finished start-up
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
    --
    -- Unit session-78106.scope has finished starting up.
    --
    -- The start-up result is done.
    Dec 08 04:10:01 uls-******** systemd[1]: Started Session 78107 of user root.
    -- Subject: Unit session-78107.scope has finished start-up
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
    --
    -- Unit session-78107.scope has finished starting up.
    --
    -- The start-up result is done.
    Dec 08 04:10:01 uls-******** CROND[67561]: (root) CMD (/usr/share/spamassassin/sa-update.cron 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/sa-update.log)
    Dec 08 04:10:01 uls-******** CROND[67562]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
    Dec 08 04:20:01 uls-******** systemd[1]: Started Session 78109 of user root.
    -- Subject: Unit session-78109.scope has finished start-up
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
    --
    -- Unit session-78109.scope has finished starting up.
    --
    -- The start-up result is done.
    Dec 08 04:20:01 uls-******** systemd[1]: Started Session 78108 of user root.
    -- Subject: Unit session-78108.scope has finished start-up
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
    --
    -- Unit session-78108.scope has finished starting up.
    --
    -- The start-up result is done
```

.

output of systemctl status httpd.service

```
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-12-08 04:26:51 PST; 53s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 68719 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 68719 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

I tried to change the port number in httpd.conf file. But I got the same error. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try check your config, validate from command `apachectl configtest`

Comment: verified and syntax ok

Comment: run this sudo journalctl -u httpd.service --since today --no-pager
and view log folder /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: Thanks.I verified the logs and understood that some certificates expired. that caused the issue.